# How to tell Swagger an attribute is a Map

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, swagger

I am developing a restful service with Jersey. However, I am using Swagger for documentation. My Model has a property with Type of Map. Swagger shows that this attribute as an Object (not a specific type). So how can I tell Swagger that this property is from type Map ?

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private Map<Integer, String> myMap;

    public Model(){
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Map<Integer, String> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }
    public void setMyMap(Map<Integer, String> myMap) {
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }
}
```

The restful service:

```
@POST
@Path("/createBundle")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ApiOperation(value = "Create Bundle ",
    notes = "",
    response = Model.class)
    public Model createBundle(Bundle bundle){
        return new Model();
    }
```

I need Swagger to show it as type of `Map<Integer, String>`.

Swagger shows the documentation as this image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a response type in the `@ApiOperation` annotation:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Find thingies as Map",
    notes = "Multiple thingies can be returned, <code>id</code> is the ID field",
    response = java.util.Map.class)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it seems that it was something not clear. I have added more details to the question

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what you added. And please add your code and generated JSON.

Comment: You do know JSON has no notion of Java types like `Map<Integer, String>`, right? You have to roll your own here, see my updated answer

Comment: @JohannesJander how this could work? unfortunately it's not working for me.