# Swagger UI incorrectly render java.util.Map

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to integrate my Spring MVC application with Swagger to get REST API documentation clean and up to date. But I run into a problem of representing java Map in swagger UI. Here are my simple controller and model:

- User

```java
@Data
@ApiModel
public class User {

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "test@example.com")
  private String email;

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "John")
  private String firstName;

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "Doe")
  private String lastName;

  @ApiModelProperty
  private Map<String, Address> addresses;

}
```

- Address

```java
@Data
@ApiModel
public class Address {

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "Calle 39 No 1540")
  private String street;

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "B1000TBU")
  private String postalCode;

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "San Sebastian")
  private String city;

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "Argentina")
  private String country;

}
```

- User Controller

```java
@RestController
@Api(value = "User Management")
public class UserController {

  @ApiOperation("Get a user profile by the email")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{email:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public User getPersonByFirstName(@ApiParam @PathVariable("email") String email) {
    return new User();
  }
}
```

For generating Swagger specification I use Swagger Maven Plugin. In the and I got next documentation:

[image]

Instead of proper type ‒ **Map[String, Address]** ‒ I got weird inline_model. On tab *Example value* the value of addresses is just empty object ‒ **{}**.

I try to specify data type of this Map field, but no of the following annotations will work:

- @ApiModelProperty(value = "addresses", dataType =
  "Map[string,com.redkite.model.Address]")
- @ApiModelProperty(value = "addresses", dataType = "java.util.Map")
- @ApiModelProperty(value = "addresses", dataType =
  "java.util.Map< java.lang.String, com.redkite.model.Address>")

Also, I try to find the answer in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411621/how-to-tell-swagger-an-attribute-is-a-map) but it does not solve my problem.

The question is ‒ Does Swagger UI support java Map at all? If not ‒ Is there some work around for fixing this issue?

I use next versions of frameworks and plugins:

- Swagger Maven Plugin ‒ 3.1.3 (generates specification of version 2.0)
- Swagger-annotations ‒ 1.5.9
- Swagger UI ‒ 2.2.10

For more information attaching [generated specification](http://ttps://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByU3kEX0cKUwa3RoTENpejhmSHc).